# jquery code to Joomla

Tags: jquery, joomla, joomla3.0

I found this really nice gallery http://jgallery.jakubkowalczyk.pl/customize-full-screen#images/large/14.jpg there I found this code and I changed the img & this :

link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="jgallery-master/css/font-awesome.min.css"

link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="jgallery-master/css/jgallery.min.css"

script type="text/javascript" src="jgallery-master/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js">

script type="text/javascript" src="jgallery-master/js/tinycolor-0.9.16.min.js">

script type="text/javascript" src="jgallery-master/js/jgallery.min.js">

script type="text/javascript">

P.S: I CAN NOT POST THE FULL CODE OR SCREENSHOT

Comment: You do realise you will have to also import the jGallery plugin too

Comment: Oh… yes. I am total beginner. I download the .zip file but this happen JInstaller: :Install: Die XML-Installationsdatei could not be found…   :(

Comment: jGallery is not a Joomla extension that you'd install on your site. It's a jQuery plugin that you'd have to link using a script tag in the site head. See http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript#External_JavaScript

Comment: Then, you can use an extension like jQuery Easy (which you do install to Joomla) to add the code in your question to the site, probably via a module. 

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327

Comment: Ok.. while I was trying to link jQuery I could find another code on there Website

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but I am already download & install "sourcerer" and I also added the code but nothing really happens http://www.gnessia.at/jana/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=13&Itemid=128&lang=de                  have I overlooked something :( ?